# Update of our tour page

Tags: discussion

The 2014 cleanup program are good under way. The tags needs to be edited still, but that can be done later. What I'm concerned at is our [tour page](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/tour).

Currently, there are no mention that shopping questions is off topic and should not be asked. Currently, the following is listed

- Anything not directly related to WordPress
- WordPress.com support issues
- Questions that are primarily opinion-based
- with too many possible answers or that would require an extremely long answer

Isn't it time for the tour page to be updated to display that plugin/theme/hosting recommendation question are of topic?. The *help -> on topic* page does correctly have these included, why not the tour page

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had added recommendations to that list.

Comment: Many thanks Rarst. Hopefully new (and existing) users will visit the page and take note.